# How can I get Latex printing with sympy in iPython console?

Tags: sympy

I am using sympy 1.10.1 under Python 3.8 on Linux Mint 20.1. On a previous computer I had no issues getting Latex output from sympy in the iPython console, but now I cannot. Texlive is installed. Please note that I do not want to install Jupyter Notebooks.

Comment: There are many different ways of using sympy and ipython separately and together. You should describe more clearly what you are doing what it is that you want. It isn't even clear to me what you mean by "Latex output" for example.